# Cannot load a large powerpoint file (~100MB) using UIWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, powerpoint, wkwebview

I'm using UIWebView to open a pptx file (~110MB) but most of my devices are not able to load the file. I think it's the problem of running out of memory.

```
self.contentWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.contentWebView.delegate = self;
self.contentWebView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.contentWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.contentWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES; // to fit the content into the webview
[self.view addSubview:self.contentWebView];
self.filename = Path;
[self.contentWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Path]]];
```

Is there any way to address this issue?

EDIT:

I've tried WKWebView, but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

how about use WKWebView instead of UIWebView

Comment: The UIWebView is part of UIKit, and I'm using it for other functions across the app. The app is pretty old, so I'm not very keen to make a big update to get around this issue if there are better ways.